# How to alert nodeName inside div element using jquery

Tags: jquery

Hi I want to alert nodeName. I am not finding the way to do it

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
var jj= $('.fa').find().get().nodeName;
alert(jj)
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="fa">
<span >sdf</span>
<span >sdf</span>
<div></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `nodeName`?

Comment: What you expect to output?

Comment: Which nodeName are you looking for? `span`?

Comment: The output should span, span , div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var jj= $( '.fa' ).get(0).nodeName
alert(jj);
```

OR

```
var jj= $( '.fa' )[0].nodeName
alert(jj);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uPyMy/1/)

---

EDIT

```
$('.fa').find('*').each(
  function(){ 
    alert(this.nodeName);
 });
```

Comment: i want to find tag inside the .fa div

Answer (score 1):

The `get` method returns an array and the `find` method needs a parameter like a selector. I'm guessing you did `find` on mistake.
How about this:

```
alert( $('.fa')[0].nodeName );
```

If you are not sure if the class actually exists try this

```
var node = $('.fa')[0];
if (node != null) alert( node.nodeName );
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the `find()` mean.

But the following code will work:

```
$(function () {
  var jj = $('.fa').get(0).nodeName;
  alert(jj)
})
```

`.get(0)` means the first element, and you can get the other elements with different index number.

Answer (score 0):

```
alert($("#elementId").get(0).nodeName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with prop method

```
var jj= $('.fa').prop("tagName")
alert(jj)
```

Please check [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b8U8w/)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are trying to find the type of first node inside the div which has class ".fa". In this case, use

```
var jj= $( '.fa' ).children().get(0).nodeName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
$(function(){
    var jj= $('.fa').find("*")[0].nodeName;
    alert(jj)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"The output should span, span , div"*

Try something like this:

```
var jj = $('.fa').find('*').map(function() {
           return this.nodeName;
         }).get().join(", ");
alert(jj);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zwCdZ/

The [`.get()` method](http://api.jquery.com/get/) returns an array of elements, and arrays don't have a `nodeName` property. To produce the result you asked for (as a string), you need to process each item in the array. I'd suggest using the [`.map()` method](http://api.jquery.com/map/), turning the result into a plain array with the [`.get()` method](http://api.jquery.com/get/), and then joining that array into a string with `.join()`.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.fa').children().each(function(){alert(this.nodeName);});
```